# Usage of String[..] Array operation

Tags: javascript

I have seen the following javascript in a webpage.

```
s = String["fromC" + aa.nodeValue];
```

May I know what is the usage of `String[...]`?

Comment: Where did you see that? I need a link or I can't believe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square-bracket notation is just another way to access object properties or methods, usually by some kind of variable as opposed to the dot notation which accesses properties by symbol or key.

Say `aa.nodeValue` was equal to the string *"harCode"*. This would work like this

```
var s = String["fromCharCode"];
```

Which is equivalent to

```
var s = String.fromCharCode;
```

So `s` is now a pointer to the static [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method on `String`.

Similarly, if `aa.nodeValue` was equal to *"odePoint"*, you would be referencing [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)

Answer (score 1):

Its just [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), written in an obfuscated way, it can be like:

```
aa = document.createTextNode("harCode");
s = String["fromC" + aa.nodeValue];
```

which would finally become `String["fromCharCode"]` which is equivalent to `String.fromCharCode`